# shadow error from Irradiance volume

Tags: lighting

I was practicing lighting in Blender.
I use Irradiance volume to bake my inside room.
[image]
However, some shadow error appears on the edge.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try increasing shadow cube sizes and indirect lighting cubemap resolutions.** This should get rid of those artifacts. EEVEE is fast because it 'guesses' what light does when it hits objects. It's basically faster in sake of losing realism.[image]